# Can SublimeLinter prevent SFTP plugins from running on save?

Tags: sublimetext3, sftp, sublimelinter

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on OSX for PHP development. When I save a file, the `SublimeLinter` plugin checks for errors, and the `SFTP` plugin uploads the file to the server. But if there are errors in a PHP file, can `SublimeLinter` be configured to prevent the `SFTP` plugin from uploading?

Answer (score 0):

No. Sadly there isn't that feature, or a way to configure it to do so without adding it to [the code base](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3).